# how to zip folder in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

need some help for laravel zip file. i have a folder in the public folder and i would like to create a zip of that folder (temp_file folder) whenever the user clicks the button.

```
public function testing()
{
    $public_dir = public_path('temp_file/');
    $zipFileName = 'myZip.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    if ($zip->open($public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $zip->addFile('file_path', 'file_name');
        $zip->close();
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream');

    $filetopath = $public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName; 
}
```

but it seems that it is not creating the zip file and i can't download it. Please need some help

Comment: According to your example, the zip-file should be empty, because you're adding non-existent files: `$zip->addFile('file_path','file_name');` and I can't see any point, where you stream the file to the client. You just define the path to the empty zip file.

Comment: i have change it to $zip->addFile($public_dir,$zipFileName); but i m getting error ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Is a directory

Comment: The first parameter is the path to the file, the second parameter is the name you want inside the zip file.

Comment: Create a file download response like `return response()->download($filetopath, $zipFileName, $headers);`

Comment: but it is not creating the zip file

Comment: Can you update the code above to your current working status?

Comment: Does the folder `temp_files` have the right permissions to save a file?

Comment: please check my answer. it may help

Answer (score 10):

Many people may not know this but [`ZipArchive::addFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) and [`ZipArchive::close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) also return a boolean to show their success (or failure). You should always check them because only the `close` method returns if the folder isn't writeable.

Then you said that nothing downloads if you call the controller action. That's right. You didn't tell the program to stream something to the client. You just set two variables, one for headers? and the other one for the exact same file path used above to open the zip file.

The following code is a working *example* (at least in a configured environment with correct folder permissions) how this procedure **can** work and get you some "inspiration" for your task.

```
public function testing()
{
    // Create a list of files that should be added to the archive.
    $files = glob(storage_path("app/images/*.jpg"));

    // Define the name of the archive and create a new ZipArchive instance.
    $archiveFile = storage_path("app/downloads/files.zip");
    $archive = new ZipArchive();

    // Check if the archive could be created.
    if (! $archive->open($archiveFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)) {
        throw new Exception("Zip file could not be created: ".$archive->getStatusString());
    }

    // Loop through all the files and add them to the archive.
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (! $archive->addFile($file, basename($file))) {
            throw new Exception("File [`{$file}`] could not be added to the zip file: ".$archive->getStatusString());
        }
    }

    // Close the archive.
    if (! $archive->close()) {
        throw new Exception("Could not close zip file: ".$archive->getStatusString());
    }
    
    // Archive is now downloadable ...
    return response()->download($archiveFile, basename($archiveFile))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything works for you, you need to check the **permission** of **each directory** at `public_path()`. 
The directory must have **0755** or **0777** permission to create and execute files.
Please check your directory permission first.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do in Popper format .
Do Like this

```
$File = 'path-ZipFile/fileName' . time() . '.zip';
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($File, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile("fullpath/filename.extinction");
    $zip->close();
}

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($File));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($File);
header("Connection: close");
```